# invalid array element at index 0: expected a datetime.date or datetime.datetime instance, got 'int' asyncpg

Tags: python, asyncpg

I'm stuck With this uneasy to interpretate error With asyncpg.
The error tells me index 0 is of wrong type, expecting datetime while receiving int:

```
asyncpg.exceptions.DataError: invalid input for query argument $1: [(None, 1000, 2001, datetime.datetime(2.... (invalid array element at index 0: expected a datetime.date or datetime.datetime instance, got 'int')
```

This is odd, cause the schema is:

```
id: bigint, 
eid: bigint, 
time: datetime, 
type: varchar(20)
```

My data looks like this:

```
data = [(None, 1000, 2001, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 20, 23, 20, 35, 71), 'Testing1'),
        (None, 1001, 2002, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 20, 23, 20, 35, 71), 'Testing2'),
        (None, 1002, 2003, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 20, 23, 20, 35, 71), 'Testing3')]
```

None is added to the first element, cause I saw that in another post, same error Without it.

And the async function:

```
async def insert(data):
    conn = await asyncpg.connect(user='username', password='password',
                             database='database', host='127.0.0.1')
    res = await conn.fetch('''
    INSERT INTO tablename (id, eid, time, type)
    (SELECT
        e.id, e.eid, e.time, e.type
    FROM
        unnest($1::tablename[]) as e
    )
''', data)
    await conn.close()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(insert(data))
```

Very unclear error, hope anynoe can help solve this.

Comment: Are you *sure* it gives the exact same error without `None`? I can see no reason at all to add it, it throws off your fields by one.

Comment: You are rigth. I'm pretty sure I tried it many times, but so i tried it again, and now it works.